# Android: Getting back to home screen after snoozing the alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using alarm in my application in which I had added snooze functionality. I want that, when I press snooze button, then I should go to home screen but not getting how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use any of the next commands, depending on your requirements:

1. [MainActivity.this.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)
2. [MainActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29)
3. start the launcher app:

code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```